The parabola V(Y-$X^2$) in $() ^2$ could it be not irreducible?
The Parabola V(Y-$X^2$) is the set of couple (x,y)∈ $() ^2$ such that $y=x^2$, p is a prime number and  is the finite field with p elements.
We observe two steps:
i)the ideal I of the parabola (ideal of polynomials which cancel on the parabola) is generated by $X^p-X$ and Y-$X^2$ . Let P(X,Y)
∈ I. Like [X,Y]= [X][Y], we begin to do the division by Y-$X^2$. P(X,Y)=(Y-$X^2$)Q(X,Y)+R(X) with R(X) polynomial in X only. Then for x ∈ , $(x,x^2)$ is on the parabola. Hence $0=P(x,x^2)= 0+R(x)$. Now, we do the division of R(X) by $X^P-X$ . R(X)= $(X^P-X)$ R1(X)+S(X) where d°(S)<p. For each x ∈ , since $x^p=x$ we have S(x)=0. Finally S(X)  is a polynomial of d°<p with p roots. So S(X) is the null polynomial. We have the annonced result.
ii) the ideal I contains $X^P-X$ and does not contain X and $X^{p-1}-1. $ Hence I is not prime.
Since the  associated ideal to the parabola is not prime, she cannot irreducible.
The proof seems correct. Is it again true if the field has $p^s$ elements (s>1)?

Title and second last sentence: irreducible, not irreductible.

Thank you very much

Over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ "the associated ideal to the parabola" is ambiguous. You could mean $(y - x^2) \subset \mathbb{F}_q[x, y]$, or you could mean the ideal of polynomial functions vanishing on the set of points $(t, t^2) \subset \mathbb{F}_q^2$, which is $(y - x^2, x^p - x) \subset \mathbb{F}_q[x, y]$ as you say.
This set of points is not what is meant by "the parabola" over a finite field, in algebraic geometry. "The parabola" is the affine scheme $\text{Spec } \mathbb{F}_q[x, y]/(y - x^2)$, and it has points not only over $\mathbb{F}_q$ but over every algebraic extension $\mathbb{F}_{q^k}$, namely the points $(t, t^2) \in \mathbb{F}_{q^k}^2$. Its "associated ideal" is $(y - x^2)$ on the nose, not $(y - x^2, x^p - x)$, and it remains irreducible because $\mathbb{F}_q[x, y]/(y - x^2) \cong \mathbb{F}_q[x]$ is still an integral domain.
Over a non-algebraically closed field $K$ it is just no longer true that an affine variety is a collection of points in $K^n$ cut out by polynomials $f_i$; it is now a more complicated gadget, which can be thought of in several different ways, but the most basic way to say it is that we regard the polynomials $f_i$ as more fundamental, and we consider their locus of vanishing not only over $K$ but over, say, all algebraic extensions of $K$. Depending on how far you want to go into scheme theory it may be necessary to go beyond field extensions as well.

I understand that the point of view to considere the parabola not in ()2 but in $k^2$ where k is a algebraic closure of  is very interesting. Without reference to schema, can we say that the ideal of this parabola in $k^2$ is $(Y-X^2)$?

I want to go in scheme theory and understand why the spectra evolue

@Boichu: yes, you can avoid the full theory of schemes by saying that an affine variety over a field $F$ is a subset $V$ of $\overline{F}^n$ cut out by polynomial equations over $F$. This equips $V$ with an action of the Galois group $\text{Gal}(\overline{F}/F)$. So the parabola in this sense consists of the infinitely many points $(t, t^2) \in \overline{\mathbb{F}_q}^2$, whose ideal is $(y - x^2)$.

I appreciate the detailed and lighted answer. I need to study that now.Thank you.
